# How do I convert integer column values to categorical or string column values dynamically in python?

Tags: python

I have a column that has the values `1,2,3....`
I need to change this value to `Cluster_1, Cluster_2, Cluster_3...` dynamically. My original table looks like below, where `cluster_predicted` is a column, containing integer value and I need to convert these numbers to `cluster_0, cluster_1...`

[image: My table looks like below]

I have tried the below code

```
clustersDf['clusterDfCategorical'] = "Cluster_" + str(clustersDf['clusterDfCategorical'])
```

But this is giving me a very weird output as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You should use proper delimiter, which will split your data into columns. Can you provide more code? Table before assignment to dataframe?

Comment: The problem was with the 'str'. I used astype as suggested by the below answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['cols']=[1,2,3,4,5]
df['vals']=['one','two','three','four','five']
df['cols'] =df['cols'].astype(str)
df['cols']= 'confuse_'+df['cols']
print(df)
```

try this , the string conversion is making the issue for you.
One way to convert to string is to use astype

Comment: clustersDf['clusterDfCategorical'] = "Cluster_" + clustersDf['clusterDfCategorical'].astype(str)
this should be the edit you should make to your code,also you may accept the answer

Comment: Yep. I did the same thing. Worked beautifully!